# Simple parallax scrolling with wallpaper animation

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make the background to slide towards left while using parallax effect. but I am having a problem that the speed of animation is changing as i change size of the browser window. i want the animation to be smooth and linear and not changing with browser size.

PS- the code is not running here properly but if you copy the code in html file seperately on your computer, it works. It doesnt even work on jsfiddle.

EDIT-> if i change to {background position: 1366px (actual width of wallpaper) } in my @keyframes animatedBack , it works fine. So problem is with the percentage.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
@keyframes animatedBack {
 from {background-position: 0 0;}
 to {background-position: 100% 0;}
}
.section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 position: relative;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 animation-name: animatedBack;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
#s1 {
 background-image: url(http://hdwplan.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/digital-background-desktop.jpeg);
}
#s2 {
 background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Background_HD_images9.jpg);
}
#s3 {
 background-image: url(http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Free_Background_Wallpaper_09.jpg);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <div class="section" id="s1">
 </div>
 <div>
 <div class="section">
     <div class="content"><h1 style="text-align:center;">2</h1></div>
 </div>
 <div>
 <div class="section" id="s3">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for animation or any kind of effect. this is a sample code, Add some content inside div with id my-content and scroll .

```
    <body>
      <div class="layer1"></div>
      <div class="layer2"></div>
<div id='my-content'></div>          //your content for scrolling
    </body>


    <style>
    body{ 
        margin:0px; 
        background:url(bg.jpg) fixed;
       }

    #my-content{ position:absolute; }

    .layer1{
        position:fixed;
        background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat 0px 200px;
        width:100%;
        height:800px;
    }
    .layer2{
        position:fixed;
        background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat 600px 400px;
        width:100%;
        height:1000px;
    }

    </style>

    <script>
    function my-parallax(){
        var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
        var layer2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
        layer1.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
        layer2.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 8)+'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", my-parallax, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: But why is  CSS not working, I dont see anything wrong there. Pls read the edited Question

Comment: You are asking .. about scrolling animation, and you need a browser's eventlistener to handle that effect . That's why -- Javascript.

Comment: i dont want animation with scroll, I just want my simple CSS animation to be smooth. No problem of scroll / no problem of Javascript.

Comment: Read css3 animation here [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)